# Image in picture element has width bigger than the asset's width

Tags: html, css

How to prevent `img` in a `picture` element to get bigger that that actual asset's dimensions? Similar as when loading an img element width height and width set to `auto`?

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x90/000/fff" />
```

```
<!-- vs. -->
```

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 1px)" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/160x90/000/fff 160w" />
  <img />
</picture>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1zbdewpc/

Comment: What about removing `"160w"` from the srcset? https://jsfiddle.net/8jr0nsav/

Comment: dropping the width part as @RokoC.Buljan suggested seems to work. although according to MDN docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#attr-srcset) "Each string in the list must have at least a width descriptor or a pixel density descriptor to be valid". But if i understand the HTML spec correctly (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#image-candidate-string)  "Zero or one of the following: A width descriptor..." means it is safe to drop the #w part.
But why does it behave like this?

Answer (score 0):

The 160w messes up the code:

**First Image:**

[image: First Image:]

**Second Image:**

[image: Second Image:]